# Genetic Inheritance

Tags: genetics

With suppression in mind consider the following in a system that requires two genes (and their products) to produce a function or phenotype:

The products of the two genes are both necessary and sufficient to produce the phenotype (fluorescent flowers). Call the genes A and B and the mutant forms a and b. What would be the ratio of phenotypes of the progeny if a heterozygous plant AaBb were allowed to self pollinate? The genes are not linked.

Now you take a plant that is aaBb and you mutate it, then allow it to self pollinate and find that one of the progeny has the fluorescent flowers. When you allow this progeny plant to self pollinate you get a ratio of 3 progeny with fluorescent flowers and 1 without. That is not the expected ratio for a reversion of the "a" gene.

When you cross this plant with the original AaBb plant you get a ratio of 3:1 also.

Propose an explanation.

Comment: Explanation? You are trying to cheat on your homework. Do it yourself!